# Error trying to use 'strtok' for a string

Tags: c++, strtok

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char *tok;
string s = "Ana and Maria are dancing.";
tok = strtok(s.c_str(), " ");
while(tok != NULL) {
    cout << tok << " ";
    tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
return 0;
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
:9:29: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from ceva.cc:2:0:
348:14: error: initializing argument 1 of ‘char* strtok(char*, const char*)’ [-fpermissive]"
```

Comment: You should consider changing the plot, by this I mean what Ana and Maria are doing, or the question will be flagged as offensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[strtok()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html) is destructive in its parsing (ie it *writes* to the string you're parsing while you're parsing it), so it takes a `char*` as a parameter, not a `const char*`.

`c_str()` returns a `const char*` since it does not expect you to write to the content of the buffer it returns.

A way to do the parsing is to [strdup()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) (ie copy) the buffer you want to work and parse that, ie;

```
char* buf = strdup(s.c_str());
tok = strtok(buf, " ");
...
```

Remember to free the copy once you're done with it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `c_str()` returns a `const char*`, because the `string` object is supposed to be the owner of the buffer where the encapsulated string is stored, so you are not entitled to modify it except through member functions of `string`.

On the other hand, `strtok()` accepts a pointer to (non-`const`) `char`, i.e. a `char*`, and this is what the compiler complains about: you are trying to pass something non-modifiable to a function that wants to modify that thing.

If I may suggest a better approach which is more idiomatic in C++11, since you are using `std::string` anyway, rather do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s = "Ana and Maria are dancing";

    std::string::size_type start = 0;
    std::string::size_type pos = s.find(" ");
    while (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string tok = s.substr(start, pos - start);
        std::cout << tok << " ";

        start = pos + 1;
        pos = s.find(" ", start);
    }
}
```

The above code also removed this directive:

```
using namespace std;
```

It is commonly considered bad programming practice (especially when placed at global namespace scope), because it easily leads to name clashes with entities that belong to the `std` namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative; I solved it by adding
    char *d = strdup(s.c_str());
    tok = strtok(d, " ");