# How to optimize strtok + atoll

Tags: c++, string, performance, optimization

Is there any good way to optimize this function in terms of execution time? My final goal is to parse a long string composed of several integers (thousands of integer per line, and thousands of lines). This was my initial solution.

```
int64_t get_next_int(char *newLine) {
    char *token=strtok(newLine, " ");
    if( token == NULL ) {
        exit(0);
    }
    return atoll(token);
}
```

**More details**: I need the "state" based implementation of strtok, so the padding implemented by strtok should exist in the final string. Atoll does not need of any kind of verification.

**Target system**: Intel x86_64 (Xeon series)

**Related topics**:

- atoi optimization: [C++ most efficient way to convert string to int (faster than atoi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826422/c-most-efficient-way-to-convert-string-to-int-faster-than-atoi)

Comment: `strtok()` has serious drawbacks, don't use it.

Comment: *Optimize* by what metric? Beauty? Memory bandwidth? Memory usage? Speed on what machine? Unclear.

Comment: Much better, thanks!

Comment: it seems at first parsing(before space character) it will returun 0 if it is non-number entry or combined alphabetic and number in such a way that alphabetic at beginning . If combined and number at beginning, it will return the number merely. So, it is not safe code for me. Without safety, It shouldn't be optimized.

Comment: You might want to specify in words what you are trying to achieve. Is the side-effect of `strtok` (stuffing a `\0` byte somewhere inside the input string) desirable? Is the behavior of `atoll` in case of errors desirable? Do you want any specific behavior in case of errors at all? Also, your question has a link to a very similar question with answers. You should specify how your question is different from the other one, and why the answers to the other question are not sufficient.

Comment: I think your code is little gobbledygook. Show what you exactly want without simplification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First off:** I find optimizing string conversion routines in signal processing chains most of the time to be totally in vain. The speed at which your system loads data in string form (which will probably happen from some mass storage, where it was put by something that didn't care about performance, since it wouldn't have chosen a string format in the first place, otherwise), and if you compare read speeds of all but clusters of SSDs attached via PCIe with how fast `atoll` is, you'll notice that you're losing a negligible amount of time on inefficient conversion. If you pipeline loading parts of that string with conversion, the time spent waiting for storage will not even be remotely filled up with converting, so even without any algorithmic optimization, pipelining/multi-threading will eliminate practically all time spent on conversion.

I'm going to go ahead and assume your integer-containing string is sufficiently large. Like, tens of millions of integers. Otherwise, all optimization might be pretty premature, considering there's little to complain about [`std::iostream` performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042110/using-scanf-in-c-programs-is-faster-than-using-cin).

Now, the trick is that no performance optimization can be done once the performance of your conversion routine hits the memory bandwidth barrier. To push that barrier as far as possible, it's crucial to optimize usage of CPU caches – hence, doing linear access and shuffling memory as little as possible is crucial here. Also, if you care for speed, you don't want to call a function every time you need to convert a few-digit number – the call overhead (saving/restoring stack, jumping back and forth) will be significant. So if you're after performance, you'll do the conversion of the whole string at once, and then just access the resulting integer array.

So you'd have roughly something like, on a modern, SSE4.2 capable x86 processor

Outer loop, jumps in steps of 16:

- load 128 bit of input string into 128 bit SIMD register
- run something like [`__mm_cmpestri`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4147,4147,4148,348,786&techs=MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX&cats=String%25252525252525252520Compare) to find indices of  delimiters and `\0` terminator in all these 16 bytes at once
- inner loop over the found indices

  - Use SSE copy/shift/immediate instructions to isolate substrings; fill the others with `0`
  - prepend saved "last characters" from previous iteration (if any – should only be the case for first inner loop iteration per outer loop iteration)
  - subtract `0` from each of the digits, again using SSE instructions to do up to 16 subtractions with a single instruction ([`_mm_sub_epi8`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4147,4147,4148,348,786&techs=MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX&cats=String%25252525252525252520Compare))
  - convert the eight 16bit subwords to eight 128 bit words containing two packed 64bit integers each (one instruction per 16bit, `_mm_cvtepi8_epi64`, I think)
  - initialize a `__mm128` register with `[10^15 10^14]`, let's call it `powers`
  - loop over pairs dual-64bit words: (each step should be one SSE instruction)

    - multiply first with `powers`
    - divide powers by `[100 100]`
    - multiply second with `powers`
    - add results to dual-64bit accumulator
  - sum the two values in accumulator
  - `store` the result to integer array

Comment: That was an interesting point. In fact, I already use some pipelining with asynchronous IO read. Also, avoiding function call was another good starting point to optimize. One additional feature I use is that while there are no data available (system is still loading strings) I perform some other stuff required in my software - and I've found my strtok+stoi being much slower compared to other parts of the system.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use something along the lines of a `std::istringstream`:

```
int64_t get_next_int(std::istringstream& line) {
    int64_t token;
    if(!(line >> token))
         exit(0);
    return token;
}


 std::istringstream line(newLine);

 int64_t i = get_next_int(line);
```

---

`strtok()` has well known [drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495527/error-trying-to-use-strtok-for-a-string), and you don't want to use it at all.

Comment: What about the issues regarding converting a cstring to isstringstream type? Does this include considerable overhead?

Comment: @rkioji _"Does this include considerable overhead?"_ Usually not.

Comment: How does this compare to sscanf?

Comment: @rkioji At least in better type safety. You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042110/using-scanf-in-c-programs-is-faster-than-using-cin) before asking again.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ great link; referred to that answer pretty often outside SO, and now, [finally in an answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38076565/4433386).

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
int n= 0;

// Find the token
for ( ; *newline == ' '; newline++)
  ;
if (*newline == 0)
  // Not found
  exit(0);

// Scan and convert the token
for ( ; unsigned(*newline - '0') < 10; newline++)
  n= 10 * n + *newline - '0';
return n;
```

Answer (score 1):

AFA I get from your code at first splitting it will return. It seems at first parsing(before space character) it will returun 0 if it is non-number entry or combined alphabetic and number in such a way that alphabetic at beginning . If combined and number at beginning, it will return the number merely. Namely, you just need a string for the conversion. So you don't need tokenizing just check the `string` is null or not. You can change return type as well. Because, *if you need a type with _exactly_ 64 bits, use `(u)int64_t`, if you need _at least_ 64 bits, `(unsigned) long long` is perfectly fine, as would be `(u)int_least64_t`*. I think your code is little gobbledygook. Show what you exactly want without simplification.

```
/*
 * ascii-to-longlong conversion
 *
 * no error checking; assumes decimal digits
 *
 * efficient conversion: 
 *   start with value = 0
 *   then, starting at first character, repeat the following
 *   until the end of the string:
 *
 *     new value = (10 * (old value)) + decimal value of next character
 *
 */
long long my_atoll(char *instr)
{
  if(str[0] == '\0')
    return -1;

  long long retval;
  int i;

  retval = 0;
  for (; *instr; instr++) {
    retval = 10*retval + (*instr - '0');
  }
  return retval;
}
```